# What is a good textbook which deals with line bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I read section 6.0 Sheaves and Line Bundles in Toric Varieties written by Cox, Little and Schenck.
I want to read the more comprehensive textbook which deals with line bundles.
Is there such a textbook written in the language of scheme theory.

Comment: I think every introductory algebraic geometry book has a chapter on divisors and line bundles. If you want something more complete, Lazarsfeld's volume I would be a good start.

Comment: The Wikipedia page on Line bundles links to this pdf by Michael Murray, which looks like it gives a nice intuitive introduction: http://www.maths.adelaide.edu.au/michael.murray/line_bundles.pdf